# Actionbar popup menu background in build tools version 22.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-theme

It appears there is an issue with gradle buildToolsVersion 22.0.0

When on buildToolsVersion 20, the below style worked perfectly to change the background colour of the overflow menu background in the actionbar

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>

<!-- Change Overflow Menu Background -->
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/ab_solid_dark_holo</item>
</style>
```

After changing the buildToolsVersion to 22 it no longer works.

Has anyone come across this and found a solution where I can remain on 22 and have the style work correctly?

Thanks to Rod_Algonquin i've narrowed it down a little further.

This is not an issue if you are using appcompat. This is only an issue if using Actionbarsherlock.

Comment: change the parent to `parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow" if you are using appcompat

Comment: You gave me an idea for testing and it appears it's an issue with Actionbarsherlock.
The above theme still works when using appcompat Actionbar, but unfortunately because actionbar sherlock is already implemented appcompat can't be used.
Updated question